# jqueryui autocomplete with ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, autocomplete

I'm trying to get response within ajax to JqueryUi autocomplete, but I can't get result in drop down box. here is script =>

```
$(function(){
    $("#user_key" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(){
            var http = false;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            if (http){
                http.open("POST","./ajax/autocomplete.php",true);
                http.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (http.status==200 && http.readyState==4){
                        this.value = http.responseText;
                    }
                };
                http.send(null);
            }
        },
        close: function(){

        }
    });
});
```

for simplify of example in `autocomplete.php` is only written `<?php echo "hello"; ?>`
how can i get this "hello" in drop down box and why it is needed to use **close:** function at the bottom of the script , thanks :)

PS. I think I'm making fault when writing **this.value = http.responseText**, when for example writing alert(http.responseText) it gets result from .php file. how can I indicate that result be written in drop down box ?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, use the `$.post()` or `$.ajax()` methods to do AJAX.

Comment: P.S. Have you fully read the [jquery UI autocomplete documenation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)?

Comment: the fact is that I don't know Ajax from Jquery , and because of I've script like that

Comment: Specifically, read the documentation regarding [remote sources](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote).

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to program with a language or framework or library you don't understand.

Comment: so in this case it is neccessary to use ajax within Jquery , yes ?

Comment: Just have the source as "/ajax/autocomplete.php".  Don't do all the other stuff otherwise it won't interact with jQuery appropriately.  Also read up on what you are using, don't just cut and copy code and expect it to work.

Comment: You tell me. If you're going to be using this technology you had better know how to. Otherwise, if someone's paying you to do it, you may get a) fired or b) sued.

Comment: I've just asked in this way if it was possible , so in this case I've to use jQuery ajax to accomplish this task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation and some of the tests I've done, you only need to set the `source` property with the url of your php script.

The jQuery UI code sends the `term` parameter in the querystring to the url you specify there: `source.php?term=hello`

So in your example, the following should work, given that you handle the querystring parameter correctly in you PHP script, which should return a JSON array.

```
$(function(){
    $("#user_key" ).autocomplete({
        source: "./ajax/autocomplete.php",
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

The JSON data returned should have the following format:

```
[{ "id" : "Item1", "label" : "Item1", "value" : "Item1" }, 
{ "id": "Item2", "label" : "Item2", "value" : "Item2" }]
```